# Save value in switch statement

Tags: android, switch-statement, settext, getvalue

How do I save a value to a textview after I select an item in the switch case in the listview alertdialog, thanks before

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(FlightActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Pilih Kota Asal");
    // add a list
    final String[] asalkota = {"Jakarta", "Medan", "Palembang", "Bandung", 
    "Yogyakarta", "Palu", "Makassar", "Padang", "Surabaya", "Palangkaraya", 
    "Solo", "Denpasar", "Madura"};
    builder.setItems(asalkota, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case 0: 
                case 1: 
                case 2: 
                case 3: 
                case 4: 
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                case 10:
                case 11:
                case 12:

                    kotaAsalFlight.setText(asalkota.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code in every case:

```
kotaAsalFlight.setText(asalkota[Your Case Number Here].toString()));
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need switch case. Just override onClick method like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
   kotaAsalFlight.setText(asalkota[which]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:  kotaAsalFlight.setText(asalkota.toString());

to : **kotaAsalFlight.setText(asalkota[which]);**

or
change switch case implementation to :

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
   kotaAsalFlight.setText(asalkota[which]);
}
```